# React is not rendering anything?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. I have this code and didn't get any console errors, still React isn't putting out anything on the screen.

This is my JSX code

```js
var appComponent = React.createClass({
getDefaultProps: function(){
    return {
        appName: "First React 
Application"
    }
},
render: function(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>{this.props.appName}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <appComponent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to solve it by capitalizing the first letter of the component, instead of appComponent, I wrote AppCompnent.

Comment: Glad to see you managed to fix it. On a side-note, try using the updated syntax of React. Have a look at their [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html). `React.createClass` is outdated.

Comment: @RoyScheffers Is the new syntax based on OOP?

Comment: Not really, its as the language evolved things changed, like write less code while it does more. If you're starting out, it'll be useful to learn the new standard.

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised there was no console output. Was there any info in the build log? That's super unhelpful.